# Multiprocessing external API requests with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, api, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a CSV containing ~600k partnumbers to be uploaded to my website's inventory. However, this CSV only contains limited information. We're missing pricing and other related information. To get this information I'm required to make requests to the provider's API, and add it into the CSV. At the moment, I've been splitting this part-file into 6 pieces and running the script on each of these files simultaneously. If I run one script it will take hours. Whereas if I split it up, it will go considerably faster.

The Process:

1. Read Partnumber from CSV
2. Make request
3. If errors, continue, and notate error
4. If inventory, write to inventory.csv with ID and warehouse info
5. Place part info into results.csv
6. Onto the next one

I was thinking that I could assign each item a unique ID, have the script request that information, go back into the original csv and finally place the information back into the original document.

How can I utilize the full potential of the system I'm running this script on?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import csv
import zeep

wsdl = '#####'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)

def get_data():
    with  open('partfile.csv')as f:
        parts = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
        with open('results.csv' , 'w+') as outfile:
            with open('inventory.csv', 'w+') as inventoryfile:
                output = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
                inventoryoutput = csv.writer(inventoryfile, delimiter=',')
                inventoryoutput.writerow([
                    'ID',
                    'WarehouseNumber',
                    'WarehouseName',
                    'QuantityAvailable'
                ])
                # Header Row
                output.writerow([
                    'ID',
                    'Make',
                    'Part Number',
                    'Price',
                    'Dealer Price',
                    'Retail Price',
                    'List Price',
                    'Core Cost',
                    'Part Description',
                    'Is Discontinued',
                    'Is Dropship Only',
                    'Is Refrigerant',
                    'Is Oversize',
                    'Is Hazmat',
                    'Sub Parts',
                    'Cross Reference Parts',
                    'Log',
                    'Total Inventory'
                ])
                itemId = 0
                for row in parts:
                    try:
                        item = client.service.ExactPartLookup('#####', '#####', row[0], row[1])
                        if (item == None):
                            raise Exception('Item is None')
                    except:
                        write_error(row[1])
                        continue


                    item = item.PartInformation_v2[0]
                    totalInventory = 0

                    data = [
                        itemId,
                        item.Make,
                        item.PartNumber,
                        item.Price,
                        item.Dealer,
                        item.Retail,
                        item.List,
                        item.CoreCost,
                        item.PartDescription,
                        item.IsDiscontinued,
                        item.IsDropShipOnly,
                        item.IsRefrigerant,
                        item.IsOversize,
                        item.IsHazmat,
                        item.SubParts,
                        item.CrossReferenceParts,
                        item.Log
                    ]

                    print(item.PartNumber)

                    if (item.Inventory != None):
                        inventory = item.Inventory.InventoryInformation_v2
                        iterator = 0
                        for i in inventory:
                            inventoryoutput.writerow([
                                itemId,
                                inventory[iterator].WarehouseNumber,
                                inventory[iterator].WarehouseName,
                                inventory[iterator].QuantityAvailable
                            ])
                            totalInventory += inventory[iterator].QuantityAvailable
                            iterator += 1

                    data.append(totalInventory)
                    itemId += 1
                    output.writerow(data)

def write_error( partNumber ):
    with open("errors.log", "a+") as errorfile:
        errorfile.write("Error! Part Number: " + partNumber + "\n")

get_data()
```

Please let me know if there is anymore information I could provide.

Thank you!

Comment: If this is working code, you probably should post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ a site dedicated to helping people improve working code.

Comment: @AChampion thanks! I wasn't aware of that.